# Lua double results showing

Tags: lua, computercraft

So my lua script is showing double results:

[image]

It should only show one of each type of fluid.

This is the part of the script :

```
function firstToUpper(str)
    return (str:gsub("^%l", string.upper))
end
function dispTanks()
mon.setCursorPos(offsetPos, 1)
mon2.setCursorPos(offsetPos,1)

    for i=1, #machines do
    -- RC Tanks --------------------------------------------
        if string.find(machines[i], "rcirontankvalvetile") 
            or string.find(machines[i], "rcsteeltankvalvetile") then                        

            if peripheral.isPresent(machines[i]) then
                periph = peripheral.wrap(machines[i])

                fluidRaw, fluidName, fluidAmount, fluidCapacity, fluidID = marik.getTank(periph)                            

                if fluidName == nil then
                -- does not display empty tanks
                elseif fluidName ~= nil then
                    mon2.setTextColor(tc)
                    x,y = mon2.getCursorPos()
                    mon2.setCursorPos(offsetPos, (y+1))
                    mon2.clearLine()
            -- marik.cString(offsetPos,(y+1), tc, right, ",")
            nameFL = firstToUpper(marik.comma(fluidName):match("[^.]*"))
            mon2.write("Tank (" .. nameFL .. ") :  " .. marik.getBuckets(fluidAmount) .. " buckets") 
        end
        end
    end
    end
end
```

I though it was not ending the showing with a "," "." or a ")" but that doesn't seem to be the case. How can i fix this?

**Pastebin edit**
This are the 2 complete codes:

- The main program : http://pastebin.com/ejVPwW4Q
- The api : http://pastebin.com/uycrzMTy

Comment: indent it properly and you might find your error...

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner with this os i have no idea what that means.

Comment: indenting, part of formatting: Putting the right number of spaces (resp. tabs) before each line of code to emphasize control flow and blocking.

Comment: Well i have no idea how to do that so maybe u could help me with a code that works :)?

Comment: Your code works (in that it generates the output you want) if it does that twice for each entry perhaps two entries for each thing exist in `machines`? If you print the value of `#machines` what do you get?

Comment: I have editted the main post with both pastebin codes. Also i haven no idea on how to print machines?

Comment: Kev30 use the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at this i would suggest taking a look into what your table looks like because the code posted above does not seem to have anything wrong with it, BUT if your table some how duplicated the machines then it would certainly print it out twice, that's where i would start to look.

Edit - and by table i mean the "array" machines

Code to debug the table "array" put this before the section of code you placed on your question..

```
for k, v in pairs(machines) do
  print(tostring(k)..": "..tostring(v))
end
```